# Best way to set up alerts on azure web job

Tags: azure-webjobs

Frankly speaking azure still does not have direct way to set up alerts on continuous  web job's so that one can get notification if web job stops for unknown reasons. After some investigation i found that logic apps are best way to do that. Here are the steps how one can achieve this

Go to azure web job, select properties and copy web hook url, username and password.
[image]

By default web hook url will have /run option at end to so remove that as you dont want to run webjob

Create a logic app setting following parameters in exact order

1. Recurrence - Your choice how frequently you want to run your logic
   app
2. Initialize a variable for example status (type - string)
3. Call Http end point giving following details which you copied
   earlier   [[image]]2]
4. Add a step of parse
   JSON response, pasting response so that logic app can create its own
   schema    [image]
5. Pick the item name for
   value you want to read for example i am using status
   [image]
6. Add a condition for failure
   [image: enter imagedescription here]
7. Send the mail or whatever you want to do

Over all your Login app will look something like this

[image]

Comment: You could also use ErrorTrigger to send message when errors occur. You could refer to this wiki.https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#errortrigger

Comment: Thank for sharing this, actually to do this i didn't wanted to write code.

Answer (score 2):

This is helpful, indeed. But I was facing issue with the web hook url authentication. The logic app connector was returning 401 – Unauthorized for the http request, as the password was encoded. Took a while to understand why it is throwing unauthorized even after providing correct credentials. Hence, copying the original password helped in that case ( if not anything else).